# Python lxml parsing svg file

Tags: python, svg, lxml

I'm trying to parse .svg files from http://kanjivg.tagaini.net/ , but I can't successfully extract the information inside.

**Edit 1:**(full file) http://www.filedropper.com/0f9ab

A part of `0f9ab.svg` looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="109" height="109" viewBox="0 0 109 109">
<g id="kvg:StrokePaths_0f9ab" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;">
<g id="kvg:0f9ab" kvg:element="嶺">
    <g id="kvg:0f9ab-g1" kvg:element="山" kvg:position="top" kvg:radical="general">
        <path id="kvg:0f9ab-s1" kvg:type="㇑a" d="M53.26,9.38c0.99,0.99,1.12,2.09,1.12,3.12c0,0.67,0.06,8.38,0.06,13.01"/>
        <path id="kvg:0f9ab-s2" kvg:type="㇄a"
    </g>
</g>
</g>
```

My .py file:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

svg = ET.parse('0f9ab.svg')
print(svg)  # <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x7f3a2f659ec8>

# AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'
print(svg.tag)

# TypeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object is not subscriptable
print(svg[0])

# TypeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object is not iterable
for child in svg:
    print(child)

# None
print(svg.find("./svg"))

# []
print(svg.findall("//g"))

# []
print(svg.xpath("//g"))
```

### Purpose

I tried all kinds of operations I could think of, but nothing gets me any data from the .svg file.
I want to extract the kanji (Japanese character) in `kvg:element="kanji"` (which are at different depth levels).

### Question

1. Is using `lxml` the wrong package for this?
2. If not, how do I extract information from my parsed .svg file?

### Other solution

- I could of course I could just read the file as a string and search
  for `kvg:element="`, but I would like to proper way of extracting xml
  / svg.
- I used `xmltodict` before, but my code became really messy extracting `kvg:element`, because they were at different depth levels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.parse()` returns an [ElementTree](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-elementtree-class), which represents the tree as a whole. To query individual nodes, you need an [Element](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class), most likely the root element of the tree.

Replace part of your code with this:

```
xml = ET.parse('0f9ab.svg')
svg = xml.getroot()
print(svg)  # <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x7f3a2f659ec8>
```

and I think you'll have some success.

Note also that `.findall()` requires a relative path and, in your case, a namespace qualifier:

```
print(svg.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g"))
```

Comment: I thought `.getroot()` was only necessary in the build in package `import xml.etree.ElementTree`, because I could successfully use the `.findall()` command on another .xml file, but now I'm getting elements, so I'm happy. However `print(svg.findall(".//g"))` still returns `[]`. I also added a link to the full file.

Comment: To find the `g` elements, you need to add in the namespace, like so: `print(svg.findall(".//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g"))`. See http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elementpath

Comment: I understand it better now. The other xml file didn't `.getroot()` because that's not necessary for e.g. `.findall()`. However you do need it to use functions such as `.tag`. My search query was just wrong, that's why I got an empty list returned.

Comment: 'xml namespace qualifier' I don't have a clue of what it is but still your code saved me!