# How to get element from svg using xpath python lxml, but returning empty list?

Tags: python-3.x, svg, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to edit an SVG file with python-3 and [lxml](https://lxml.de/).
So far, I'm stuck on getting an element form the SVG with xpath.

```py
from lxml import etree

boarder = etree.parse('boarder.svg')

Bd = boarder.xpath('//g/path')

print(Bd)
```

When I run the code, I get back:

```py
[]
```

Which is an empty list. 
I'm tring to access the `g/path` element as an element so that I can change its attributes.

This is the SVG I'm working with *('boarder.svg')*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 10 10"
   height="10mm"
   width="10mm">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(0,-287)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="rect1379"
       d="m 1.1663527,287.97964 h 7.6672946 v 7.6673 H 1.1663527 Z"
       style="opacity:0.95;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.89999998;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

So far I've already tryed:

- Adding a name space to xpath.

  - [Python XPath lxml could not read SVG path element due to empty namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957772/python-xpath-lxml-could-not-read-svg-path-element-due-to-empty-namespace)
- Getting the document root of `g` in an attempt to accessit it as an element.

  - [Python lxml parsing svg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469870/python-lxml-parsing-svg-file)

Comment: Please show us what you actually tried. It does work if you take the namespace into account: `Bd = boarder.xpath('//svg:g/svg:path', namespaces={"svg": "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"})`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the element before and after?

Comment: @mzjn I'm still pritty green at xml. I didn't know that I had to add `svg:` and have the name space defined. I thought just setting the `namespaces` was enough. If I use `namespaces={ * : "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"}`, can I leave out the `svg:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find `svg` element try following xpath.Use `local-name()` or `name()`

```
from lxml import etree,html

boarder = etree.parse('boarder.svg')
Bd = boarder.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]//*[local-name()="g"]/*[local-name()="path"]/@id')[0]
print(Bd)
Bd = boarder.xpath('//*[local-name()="svg"]//*[local-name()="g"]/*[local-name()="path"]/@d')[0]
print(Bd)
```

OR

```
Bd = boarder.xpath('//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"]/*[name()="path"]/@id')[0]
print(Bd)
Bd = boarder.xpath('//*[name()="svg"]//*[name()="g"]/*[name()="path"]/@d')[0]
print(Bd)
```

### Output:

```
rect1379
m 1.1663527,287.97964 h 7.6672946 v 7.6673 H 1.1663527 Z
```

Comment: Writing path expressions like that is unnecessarily complicated. The proper way is to define a namespace with a prefix, and then prefix element names.

Comment: @MathiasMüller how can I do that? could you please provide any code example?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to mzjn's comment on OP, I sussed out a way to do this a bit more generically/nicely:

```py
boarder = etree.parse('boarder.svg')
ns = boarder.getroot().nsmap
Bd = boarder.xpath('//g/path', ns)
print(Bd)
```

This also works with find, findall, and iterfind.